# Finding the joint distribution function, given the joint density function.

Tags: probability

I have the joint density function given by $$f(x,y) = 1 \hspace{2mm}\mathrm{for}\hspace{2mm} 0 \leq x \leq 2, \max\{0,x-1\} \leq y \leq \min \{1,x\}, $$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise. And I want to find the joint distribution function.

My initial idea was to split it into two cases, where $x < 1$ (where we then have $0 < y < x$) and $x > 1$ (where we then have $x-1 < y < 1$), and solve the integral $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x 1\hspace{1mm} dy dx + \int_1^2 \int_{x-1}^1 1 \hspace{1mm} dydx, $$

but apparently that is completely wrong. The solution is divided into six cases, where the first case is $F(x,y) = 1$ for $x > 2, y > 1$, and that does make sense to me. But after that I'm completely lost. I don't even understand why they are dividing the solutions into these particular cases. For example, the second case is $F(x,y) = y$ for $0 < y < 1$ and $x-1 > y$. But I have no idea why I should be considering those specific bounds or overall how to attack this problem.

Comment: You mentioned $0 \le x \le 1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Whoops, no. Editing now. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following picture

[image]

We seek to find $F(x_0,y_0)=Pr(X<x_0,Y<y_0)$. As you can see if $x_0<0$ or $y_0<0$ the probability is zero. Therefore we assume $x_0,y_0>0$. For $x_0<1$we have:$$F(x_0,y_0)=\dfrac{1}{2}\{\min(x_0,y_0)\}^2$$and for $1<x_0<2$ if $y_0<x_0-1$ we have $$F(x_0,y_0)=y_0$$ and for $y_0>x_0-1$ $$F(x_0,y_0)=y_0-\dfrac{1}{2}(y_0-x_0+1)^2$$ so for $1<x_0<2$$$F(x_0,y_0)=y_0-\dfrac{1}{2}\max\lbrace 0,y_0-x_0+1\rbrace^2$$if $x_0>2$ it is clear that $F(x_0,y_0)=\min(y_0,1)$

Comment: I don't quite understand the graph. Especially not the second part (right side of x=1). I think I understand how you then find the answers from the graph, but not the graph itself...

Comment: The graph in fact is the support set of x and y defined in ur question. I just illustrated it and implied what I needed by dividing it to subsets

Comment: I would think that the right side of the graph would look a bit different since the marginal density for $f_X(x)$ is $2-x$. (I feel like a bit of an idiot but I don't have a teacher for this class so I'll have to ask my dumb questions here.)

Comment: Neither do i.... It is OK ..... The only thing you need to check is that the area of the parallelogram is unit as is expected to be because of this property of distribution function also the PDF of x can be attained from that parallelogram(I didn't check it myself for whether it is wrong or not)

Comment: I've solved the problem, using the graph. But now I have another question: If we didn't have that $f(x,y) = 1$ for $0 < x < 2$ and $\max(0,x-1) < y < \max(1,x)$, could we still use the same "method" as we did above? (If we'd have $f(x,y) = 2xy$, instead, for example.)

Comment: Not unfortunately since the graph wouldn't be homogeneous and it was bolder in some region of the parallelogram and lighter in other regions. In that case you should use the direct calculations.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really let this go. I cannot figure out how to set it up with the bounds when doing in the direct way. I've tried looking at examples and follow the same reasoning but it doesn't work and makes no sense to me. You don't happen to know how to choose the bounds in the integrals?